# Does bridging amplifiers affect their sound?

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit

If you'd bridge two IC amps (correctly) would their tone, THD, 'quality' be affected?
(in other words - their recognizable characteristics)

And how do you calculate bridged amplifier output?
 (I.E.  single 5w, bridged 8w)

I am giving a few example schematics:

LM383
[image]

TDA2030

[image]

Comment: Your first circuit is not a bridge: U2 is not connected to the input, so it can deliver (at best) a constant output. It is just a "virtual ground" circuit.

Comment: Interesting.. never would have thought. Sorry to bother but this one is bridged, right? http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-oP16OMEbuDU/UcWXOw1r9SI/AAAAAAAAAu8/mYivFDPLMOY/s1600/Build+a+15W+Bridge+Audio+Amplifier+Circuit+based+TDA2002.jpg

Comment: Can't say, possibly. But when you want a bridge, why not take a dedicated bridge chip? Most chips intended for in-car use are bridged, like TDA7560, TDA7375A, TEA2025B, even the tiny TDA7052.

Comment: What Wouter says + if you would use such a dedicated bridge (or a stereo amplifier which can also be used in a bridge configuration) then in the **datasheet** it would list the THD for either configuration. Also don't get "stuck" on this THD because with the likes of TDA2030 etc THD is only significant for high power. Any amplifier will distort at high power levels. These are not the kind of amplifiers you'd use to drive your $1000 speakers anyway. Also: any amplifier will distort at low levels. The question is, can you hear it ? Most people can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sources of distortion in all power Amps.

- (warning: I will be using "hand-waving" arguments to prevent math getting in the way for some to understand)

  - 1) **Voltage clipping  "hard clipping"** very noticable harmonics(ignore for now)
  - 2) **Current gain "soft clipping"** by rapid reduction in hFE

For an interactive live tool select [this java app.](http://www.falstad.com/fourier/)

- select Square or sine wave, tick boxes for Mag/phase & Log
- modify wave with asymmetry, with mouse click/drag and observe harmonics created
- listen to it by ticking [x] sound box and hear it

2) continued

- this threshold is current dependent due to Rce when Vce ~<=2V

  - Rce= incremental Vce/Ice slope due to saturation
  - where hFE approaches 10% of maximum linear hFE or near 10

    - as hFE rapidly reduces THD rapidly increases or soft distortion limit
    - distortion includes harmonic distortion (HD), InterModulation Distortion,IMD
    - where THD=IMD+HD (total harmonic distortion)
    - IMD has the effect of spurious analog products with sum & difference f.out
      = f1 and f2  produces some f1 +/-f2 , +/-2f2 etc

    **- the mixing of all frequencies is due to gain modulation effects of hFE reduction**

    - fortunately all this THD can be reduced by larger Vcc or BRIDGING
    - unless to approach the current limit of driver with very low Z load
    - power stage negative feedback help a lot but not perfect
    - e.g. 40dB open loop gain with 20dB closed loop gain in final stage
    - reduces THD by 20dB
    - too much open loop gain in power amp causes phase shift
    - phase shift with negative feedback causes instability
    - then like Op Amp requires integration and significant bandwidth limiting
    - so **power amps always have low open loop voltage gain but very high current gain**
    - high linearity designs for symmetrical gain are achieved by better current mirrors or shared constant current sources for bias on +,- sides on any complementary output stage.
    - asymmetry for positive and negative waves ( amplified by +ve and -ve driver output stage with different parts.) is also a major contributor
    - if current gain on +wave is different than negative swing then a low Z load will produce different voltage or power swings

**- this asymmetry increases THD**

example;

- We know a perfect square wave is 50:50 symmetric
- but as I recall 49:51 ratio 2nd harmonic goes from -infinity in theory to -23dB approx or almost 1% THD
- I used to be able to measure the square wave duty cycle error to any accuracy by correlating the 2nd harmonic level to asymmetry

  - this is critical for AM demodulators and HDD data separators for recovering high speed data without symmetry error as this adds to Bit Error rate`slope
    .

> - the same thing happens to power Amps with a sine wave with hFE symmetry error except the error is called THD

When voltage is doubled , current is doubled and asymmetry and THD accelerates rapidly when the AC current approaches the Class AB DC bias current, ( further amplifying the difference in ac current gain )

- when does this occur?

  - When Vce approaches 2V or less, hFE drops dramatically by 50 to 80% resulting in distortion but Voltage negative feedback gain of 20 dB reduces this distortion by 90% until the current gain becomes starved by Vce saturation. (Vce<2V)
  - in a 12V car Amp this applies to both drivers from 12V and ground thus reducing the available output swing significantly.
  - thus bridging doubles the available output voltage swing but also doubles the current and current asymmetry adds as well as multiplies but approaching the current limits quicker.

If ac current gain was perfectly symmetrical and constant, there would be no distortion. Which is why Vacuum tube Amps with very high voltage were "ultra linear" and popular among some folks when staying within "limits", (which is another story altogether for soft limiting of transformers)

Answer (score 3):

The most important consideration is : how well can each amplifier drive half the nominal impedance?

For example, one of your example circuits shows a bridged amplifier driving 8 ohms : how well does each half-bridge drive 4 ohms?

If it maintains its full output voltage into half the impedance, doubling its power from 5W (8 ohms) to 10W (4 ohms), without any increase in distortion, then the bridged amplifier will sound fine supplying 20W into 8 ohms.

But if its output doesn't double, or the distortion increases into a lower impedance, that's exactly what you'll hear in the bridged amplifier (only 3dB louder).

And if you speaker is only 4 ohms like many car audio speakers, then the question becomes, how well can each amplifier drive 2 ohms?